# EAN API Not Give Correct Currency at Hotel Information Page

Tags: php, web-services, api, http, https

I have try to learn web service using  EAN Hotel API but in their api tester
(http://devhub.ean.com/apitester/index.html) i have try to change Currency USD to any other like INR

and i have use this url

```
https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/info?cid=441255&minorRev=9199&apiKey=rbk3y67mm4e94rbgvk48t6x4&locale=en_US&currencyCode=INR&xml=%3CHotelInformationRequest%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3ChotelId%3E122212%3C%2FhotelId%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coptions%3E0%3C%2Foptions%3E%0A%3C%2FHotelInformationRequest%3E
```

this url generated at Hotel Information Tab at API Tester.

but not getting currency in INR.

So am i am not getting actual problem.

I think that there is API Problem.

I have contact their developer not giving response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated

Try this

```
https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/avail?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_US&currencyCode=INR&xml=%3CHotelRoomAvailabilityRequest%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3ChotelId%3E106347%3C%2FhotelId%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CarrivalDate%3E9%2F16%2F2013%3C%2FarrivalDate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CdepartureDate%3E9%2F18%2F2013%3C%2FdepartureDate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CincludeDetails%3Etrue%3C%2FincludeDetails%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRoomGroup%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRoom%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CnumberOfAdults%3E2%3C%2FnumberOfAdults%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRoom%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRoomGroup%3E%0A%3C%2FHotelRoomAvailabilityRequest%3E
```

You first select room availability and change currency in url.

Results are came from indian rupees.

api tester [Link](https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/avail?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_US&currencyCode=INR&xml=%3CHotelRoomAvailabilityRequest%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3ChotelId%3E106347%3C/hotelId%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CarrivalDate%3E9/16/2013%3C/arrivalDate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CdepartureDate%3E9/18/2013%3C/departureDate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CincludeDetails%3Etrue%3C/includeDetails%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRoomGroup%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRoom%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CnumberOfAdults%3E2%3C/numberOfAdults%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/Room%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C/RoomGroup%3E%0A%3C/HotelRoomAvailabilityRequest%3E)

Comment: this file not print any data in my localhost

Comment: @Patel Dixit curl enable in your local system?

Comment: yes currency working with all option but not working with Hotel Information Tab. Suggest Solution For Hotel Information

Comment: have you got correct reply at API Tester for hotel Information tab?

Comment: this is new url https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/info? your answer url is this https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/avail

Comment: check with this new url and reply me

Comment: @Patel Dixit this is a description for hotels. this is not change for all currencies. if you want to get the room rate details use api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/avail this url

Comment: Just you think description are in text area boxes. typed from hotel owners. not expedia.

Comment: hotel details page you can use 2 api urls. 1 st one info get all details from hotel. second one avail get all available rooms list and rate details from your expected currency

Comment: take this link there is demo of API http://www.travelnow.com/templates/440815/ if we want to change currency at hotel info page then we can change in that demo. how it is possible to do ?  you can get to navigate hotel info page after click on hotel name .

Comment: i think that both avail and info do same ... you are right may be. but just want to confirm

Comment: but there are doing mistake by API developer . so if they are not providing currency changing features at info page then why they put?

Comment: i understand your problem. you see the info page. info page included the room avail request. so only its shows all room details

Comment: Simply you can do hotel details section use info url and bottom of the page you show the room details using avail url

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35732/discussion-between-patel-dixit-and-nathan-srivi)